# Detecting exceptions upon raising

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I want to detect when certain exception is raised anywhere in the application, whether or not it was rescued higher on the call stack, and regardless of the thread it was thrown in. Is this possible?

I could possibly override Kernel's raise method, but I wonder if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding the "initialize" method of the exception class.

```
class MyCustomError < Exception
  alias_method :old_initialize, :initialize

  def initialize
    puts "hello"
    old_initialize
  end
end
```

The following behavior occurs:

```
begin
  puts "test"
  fail MyCustomError
rescue
end
```

IRB output:

```
test
hello
=> nil
```